# How to start/stop Neo4j server programatically from a browser?

Tags: neo4j

is there a way to start/stop NEo4j community edition server programatically, using a browser script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, so I would suggest you to write a simple service that will expose a rest endpoint to trigger neo4j start and stop scripts, deploy it on the server.